# Modeling a Salesforce Design

Tags: fields, data-model

BACKGROUND
I'm on a committee for a non-profit that is currently using SalesForce, where the setup was fairly ad hoc. As is to be expected, that situation has resulted in reporting errors. I have listed and analyzed the fields and their semanitic meaning in a document, but I would like to produce a model of the relationships that can be shown to decision makers.

QUESTION
I have a subscription to an online tool for modeling, and I was wondering whether a Salesforce setup would fit into an ER diagram?

Specifically, an Account has one visible field: Type. After you choose a Type, the available fields show. For clarity, I am considering modeling each Type in it's own table with its unique fields. Where I get stuck is that each Type is mutually exclusive, and I'm not sure how to express that in an ER diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the relationships using the schema builder that is built into Salesforce.

In order to do that go to Setup -> Build -> Schema Builder, once there a map of all the fields and their relationships becomes visible.

If you want to model your own setup, you can subscribe a developer edition, create your fields and the use the schema builder to visualize the relationships between them.

Comment: This is closer to the answer than what I had before, but instead of the model of the current set up, it's more like a generic case study model.